# Need Help Creating Symbols

Tags: support, mathjax

I am sorry I need to ask this, but how in the world can I insert mathematical symbols into my questions and answers such as lim, integrals, sums, etc.

(I'm new)

Answer (score 3):

See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) link for a tutorial on how to insert symbols in your questions. For future questions recall that the appropriate site to ask questions **about math.SE** but *not about mathematics* is **meta.math.SE** and that there is a [search engine](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/search?q=insert+symbols+question) that works quite decently.